# current page link adds it self onto a new link once clicked

Tags: html, svg, hyperlink, relative-path

My working site directory is set up like this.

[image]

When linking from `index.html` to `proj1.html` I am having the issue of the link to `proj1.html` `indiv_project_pages/proj1/proj1.html` stay attached to the page url when **I specify a new page link**

#### Example

I have linked from `index.html` to `proj1.html` and now I want to link to `proj2.html` The issue occurs when I click on the svg link `<a xlink:href="indiv_project_pages/proj2/proj2.html">...</>` which should lead me to `proj2.html` but instead I get this..

Cannot GET `/indiv_project_pages/proj1/indiv_project_pages/proj2/proj2.html`

I'm noticing that I'm getting the current page path `/indiv_project_pages/proj1/` added onto the link I want to go to `indiv_project_pages/proj2/proj2.html`. If I delete the current page path then I am successfully linked to `proj2.html`.

Is there a way to prevent the current page relative url `/indiv_project_pages/proj1/` from being added to `/indiv_project_pages/proj2/proj2.html` ??

Answer (score 0):

`herf`'s are relative to the HTML file they're being targeted from.

If the link you provided in the question is inside `proj1.html`, then in order to get to `proj2.html` you need to go one folder 'up' (using `../`) where you'll find yourself inside `indiv_project_pages` and keep on from there.

To sum up, your `href` should be: `../proj2/proj2.html`.